# How to use the Zebra Printer Plugin with Apache Cordova and PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I am attempting to build an application for displaying my inventory online. Part of that requires to print a label and apply it to my inventory. The application itself works fine.

The problem is with the Printer I have chosen. I have purchased a iMZ320 Zebra printer. I need the plugin to have it work on my current application IOS and Android this has proven to be beyond the skill set of my team.

I found this, it's only for Android:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-zbtprinter

Input on creating a plugin for IOS and Android applications for a Zebra iMZ320 is what I need.

We are not using a desktop app, we only developed on android and iOS
Our target devices are Android 4/5/6 and iOS 7/8/9. We use the CLI to initialize project code, then switch to eclipse to continue development.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been working with the android plugin and had a rummage around out of curiosity.

It seems that the plugin calls **cordova.exec** to communicate with the underlying native platform, see here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michael79bxl/zbtprinter/master/www/zbtprinter.js

In the android version there is a java file that wraps and calls the appropriate methods in the SDK: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michael79bxl/zbtprinter/master/src/android/com/github/michael79bxl/zbtprinter/ZebraBluetoothPrinter.java

It looks fairly straightforward. You'll have to do the equivalent for iOS of course.

If I were doing this I'd probably start with the following resources:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/
https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html

Hope this helps.